What is the glory of vrindavana in shastras
Maybe in puranas like Padma Purana, glory of vrindavana is sung.What is it's glory?

The glory of Vrindavana is told by Lord Shiva to Narada in the Padma Purana Patala-Khanda Chapter 82. after hearing from Lord Krishna. Sample verse:

Know this my beloved Rādhikā to be a great deity. Around her see her
friends in hundreds and thousands. O Rudra, they are eternal as I
having an eternal body. The cowherds, cows, cowherdesses and this my
Vṛndāvana always (exist). All this is eternal, and full of the joy of
intelligence. Know this called Ānandakanda (‘the root of delight’) to
be my Vṛndāvana, merely by entering which a man would not again get
into the worldly existence. The fool who, after having reached my
grove, goes elsewhere, would be self-killer only. I have told the
truth and the truth (only). I never leave Vṛndāvana and go anywhere
else. With her I always live here only. O Rudra, I have thus told
everything (I) had in mind. Tell me now, what else do you want to
hear.”

Sri Garga Samhita is full of the beautiful glories of Vrindavan.

वैकुण्ठान् नापरो लोको न भूतो न भविष्यति एकं वृन्दावनं नाम वैकुण्ठाच् च
परात् परम्
No place is better than Vaikuṇṭha. There never was such a place, nor
will there ever be. Still, better than Vaikuṇṭha is the place named
Vṛndāvana.

Glories are Vrindavana are found in the Sanat Kumar Samhita.

सखायः पितरौ गोपा गावो वृन्दावनं मम नित्यम् एव सर्वम् एतत्
चिद्-आनन्द-रसात्मकम्
My gopa friends, parents, cows, and this land named Vṛndāvana are all
eternal. They are spiritual, blissful, and sweet like nectar.

Glory of Vrindavana from the Harivamsha Purana:

I have heard that there is a charming forest on the bank of Yamuna
abounding in profuse grass, endued with all the virtues and freed of
thorns and insects. It is named Vrindavana. It is filled with fruits,
water and Kadamba trees.

In the Gautamiya Tantra, Krishna says to Narada:

Every part of this beautiful Vrindavana is My abode. Every creature or
demigod who lives in this place will attain Goloka dhama after death.
The cowherd girls who live in My abode are yoginis. The five yojanas
of Vrindavana forest are like My body and the spinal cord of the body
is the Kalindi River, which flows with nectarean water. Deities and
other spirits live here in invisible bodies. And I, living within
every being, never leave this place. My appearance and disappearance
has been enacted in every age. The divine and glorious illumination of
this place is beyond worldly vision. The glories of Vrindavana are
beyond anyone's calculation. People say Vrndavana covers sixteen
krosa, and in the Sastra it is said Vrndavana extends five yojanas.
Whoever has darsana of Govinda in Vrindavana never goes to Yamalaya,
but attains the destination of pious persons. The temple of Sri
Govindadeva is situated in Vrindavana and is surrounded by devotees. A
fortunate person can have His darsana.

In the Skanda Purana, Narada Muni says:

In Vrindavana the temple of Govindadeva is surrounded by devoted
worshipers. I prefer to live there. O king, in this world Vrindavana
is the Vaikuntha of Govinda. Vrinda and other female devotees of
Krishna also remain there। O Mahapala, those great souls who get
darsana of Govinda in Vrindavana are the most glorified persons in
this world.

In the Adi Varaha Purana, Sri Vishnu declares:

O Prithvi, this twelfth
forest, Vrindavan, is the destroyer of all vices and it is protected
by Vrindadevi. It is certainly My favorite place. Here I will perform
pastimes with My gopas and gopis in the famous beautiful places which
are beyond the attainment of the demigods.

Above are a few quotes. There're many other references in the scriptures to the glories of Vrindavana Dham.
